# How to write applescript to that closes a desktop space?

Tags: applescript

The below is a script to 1) click the 'add desktop' button 2) click on the last space added to go to it

```
on run
    my openSpace()
end run

on openSpace()
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application "Mission Control" to launch
        tell group 2 of group 1 of group 1 of process "Dock"
            click (every button whose value of attribute "AXDescription" is "add desktop")
            tell list 1
                set countSpaces to count of buttons
                delay 0.5
                click button (countSpaces)
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end openSpace

on closeSpace()
    
end closeSpace
```

However, I'm also trying to write a script to close a space. I'm having trouble finding which button/attribute to click. Accessibility inspector can't give me what I need, so in need of some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing under **macOS Catalina**, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works for me to close the last *desktop/space* showing in **Mission Control**:

```
my closeSpace()

on closeSpace()
    tell application "Mission Control" to launch
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        tell list 1 of group 2 of group 1 of group 1 of process "Dock"
            set countSpaces to count of buttons
            if countSpaces is greater than 1 then
                perform action "AXRemoveDesktop" of button countSpaces
            end if
        end tell
        delay 0.25
        key code 53 --  # Esc key on US English Keyboard
    end tell
end closeSpace
```

---

**Notes:**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* what tested on a system using a single monitor. Systems with multiple monitors and if **Mission Control** preferences has **Displays have separate Spaces** checked, then additional coding may be necessary.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* above, as coded, may not actually remove the last *Desktop*. If the last *button* showing in **Mission Control** is a **Full Screen View** *application window*, then the `perform action "AXRemoveDesktop" of button countSpaces` just knocks the **Full Screen View** *application window* out of **Full Screen View**.

If this is an issue for you, then to work around this and actually close the last *Desktop*, then use the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* as the `closeSpace()` *handler*:

```applescript
on closeSpace()
    tell application "Mission Control" to launch
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        tell list 1 of group 2 of group 1 of group 1 of process "Dock"
            set buttonNames to the name of UI elements
            set buttonNames to the reverse of buttonNames
            set i to the length of buttonNames
            repeat with buttonName in buttonNames
                if contents of buttonName is equal to ("Desktop " & i as text) then
                    if i is greater than 1 then
                        perform action "AXRemoveDesktop" of button i
                        exit repeat
                    end if
                else
                    set i to i - 1
                end if
            end repeat
        end tell
        delay 0.25
        key code 53 --  # Esc key on US English Keyboard
    end tell
end closeSpace
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: @Jordan Farris, Please see the **Notes:** _section_ of my updated answer as it address some afterthoughts that may be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something to close the *current* space, not the last one and I found this here: https://talk.macpowerusers.com/t/automating-spaces-in-mission-control/30877/16
I ended up using Keyboard Maestro to bind a keyboard shortcut to run the AppleScript - no disabling SIP or whatever.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution I made using the window tiling manager [yabai](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai).

Requires `yabai` and `jq` installed.

Save this into a file such as `close_current_space.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

index=$(yabai -m query --spaces --space | jq .index)

osascript -e \
  "tell application \"System Events\"
    do shell script quoted form of \"/System/Applications/Mission Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission Control\"
    delay 0.3
    perform action \"AXRemoveDesktop\" of button $index of list 1 of group \"Spaces Bar\" of group 1 of group \"Mission Control\" of process \"Dock\"
    delay 0.5
    do shell script quoted form of \"/System/Applications/Mission Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission Control\"
  end tell"
```

Then running that in a terminal will close the current active space.

I've also adapted it to handle multiple displays like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

display=$(yabai -m query --displays --display | jq .index)
spaceIndex=$(yabai -m query --spaces --space | jq .index)
actualIndex=$(($(yabai -m query --displays --display | jq ".spaces | to_entries | .[] | select(.value == $spaceIndex) | .key")+1))

osascript -e \
  "tell application \"System Events\"
    do shell script quoted form of \"/System/Applications/Mission Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission Control\"
    delay 0.3
    perform action \"AXRemoveDesktop\" of button $actualIndex of list 1 of group \"Spaces Bar\" of group $display of group \"Mission Control\" of process \"Dock\"
    delay 0.5
    do shell script quoted form of \"/System/Applications/Mission Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission Control\"
  end tell"
```

I've bound that script to a keystroke using [skhd](https://github.com/koekeishiya/skhd) and it works great.

Cheers!